Whistleblown info on department cuts. Some students investigated and traced back my answers to my real identity. What are the potential consequences?
I'm a 5th year PhD student who is at a university with major budget issues. Long story short, I posted on Reddit that my particular department planned on cutting one of their oldest programs (which is now official news). I walked past a meeting and heard a faculty member loudly say, "So, the plan is... to cut [program name]." This wasn't eavesdropping like most accused me of doing in this case. I put that information out there since I felt it was important for students to know early so they could seek their own funding. I also did it because I thought faculty were under some sort of NDA or agreement to not say any speculative plans. So, I thought I did them a favor.
Instead, many faculty, graduate students, and staff are upset at me. Fortunately, I haven't had any threats or messages in real life berating me quite yet. If so, I'm making sure I'm ready and prepared for those moments.
Many argued that the information didn't need to be whistle blown or anything, but I disagree since the intent was to protect the students and they can pivot accordingly. This also won't be an entirely big deal since I now know I want to probably be a research technician (see my other recent post) anyway and won't be using my PhD at all. However, what else could this potentially affect that I haven't considered at all? I've heard some say that it will affect letters of recommendation and whatnot so I can try and secure alternatives ASAP if that's the case.

I’ve been in plenty of meetings where the plan was to cut something IF the situation required it. Until that situation occurs, there would not be a cut. In the end you were right. But that was not a foregone conclusion when you overheard stuff.

@JonCuster I hear where you're coming from there. At the same time, I don't see an issue with students having a "plan B." I almost always have contingency plans if something happened to me academically, professionally, or even interpersonally. Some say I'm expressing my anxiety there, but I don't see anything wrong with applying my anxious tendencies to protect myself and others. My department couldn't protect me when my first PhD advisor dropped me and kept moving the goalpost in a capricious manner, so why should I have expected them to help the students out?

‘I put that information out there since I felt it was important for students to know early.’ As the apt expression goes That ain’t your story to tell. There was also the possibility you heard consensus on a proposal from one committee, maybe simply making a recommendation, at least at the time. Good luck!

Your title only mentions that ”students […] traced back your answers”. Does actual faculty know, and did that matter do those students actually know or just suspect?

@MisterMiyagi Hopefully, this answers your question. I don't know if the faculty know. There's also no "smoking gun" that explicitly traces everything back to me either. Folks just put two and two together since I made a vague description of my outside job and folks deduced from there it was me since I was the only one who worked a full time job like that. I'm guessing it mattered to those students since many were concerned about whether some info might be misleading about another program expected to be affected down the road and were likely upset at that info.

This does not in any way constitute "whistleblowing", unless you had reason that the plan was to intentionally keep the students who would be negatively impacted by this in the dark about it. Which you presumably didn't. On the contrary, it's absolutely improper not to give the department a chance to communicate this to the students themselves. (And I am not even touching on the fact that you were treating an overheard fragment of a sentence as fact.)

@AdamPřenosil - Indeed. OP isn't a whistleblower, they're a gossip.

"I thought faculty were under some sort of NDA or agreement to not say any speculative plans. So, I thought I did them a favor."  This is nonsense.  You did it because you wanted to, not to help anyone else, which you did not do because you created suspicion and a bad atmosphere.

@AdamPřenosil Especially considering that many places will have a policy of "privately inform the impacted employees/students first, and not announce things more widely until several weeks later".  This being precisely to allow them to (as OP says in another comment) "have a Plan B" in place before everything goes public.  Announcing it on Reddit might mean that other universities change their own programmes in response, which will disadvantage those students, and possibly prevent them from being able to "have a Plan B".

@Aruralreader Or, even, that the context of the conversation might merely have been referring to something like "which programs are we going to prominently list in the limited space on the first page of our prospectus?"  Something getting "cut" doesn't always refer to budgets.

@StephenG-HelpUkraine Their actions, while ill-advised could well have been well-intentioned. You don't have any special insight into their internal thought process.

@barbecue If experience has taught me anything it's that we all tend to rationalize our mistakes later on.  I really doubt the OP was thinking at the time that other people were prevented from spreading this info by an NDA, but if they did, the next thought should have been that the NDA was there to prevent rumors being spread that would cause other knock on problems.

@StephenG-HelpUkraine: You seem quick to assume the worst motivations from OP, while giving a very charitable benefit of the doubt to the intentions of a possible NDA.  While I agree OP was probably misguided here and at best jumping the gun, a naïve feeling “they shouldn’t be hiding this information from us!” seems a very plausible motivation; and conversely, NDA’s/secrecy are sometimes used for good purposes, but very often less benignly, e.g. to forestall opposition to unpopular cuts, without regard for whether the late notice leaves affected people in a worse situation.

I understand your perspective, but also understand the perspective of those who would prefer that you didn't leak the overheard information. When cuts are planned, managers like to think carefully about how and when to release the information so that they don't have people feeling worried and unhappy more than necessary before all the details have been decided and so that affected people can be told directly (which is more respectful) rather than having to hear about it through the grapevine.
I've worked in a place where everyone knew cuts were coming, but nobody knew yet exactly who would be affected, how that would be decided, or how those who weren't directly affected would be impacted by the restructure. It was not a happy time. Morale plummeted and nobody could concentrate on their work. In your case, you might have had a good idea that a program might be cut, but you didn't know the details such as whether they would be able to offer transfer to another program for students affected or whether there would be job losses among staff associated with the program.
To answer the question: you have probably already experienced the consequences: people are upset with you. This might affect your relationships within the program and, as you say, could potentially affect your references. Your options are to keep doubling down on saying that you did the right thing or to acknowledge that you might have shown poor judgement, apologise, and say that you have learned from the experience.
If you stick to your guns, you might win the admiration of those who agree with your actions, but those who don't agree will judge you even more harshly.
If you acknowledge an error of judgement and apologise, it is more likely that you will be forgiven.
Just to add: as you are a student, that is probably the full extent of the consequences. If you were an employee, the consequences for leaking confidential information could be more severe, including being fired for misconduct and worse.

Gotcha. I'll consider an apology then. I am a PhD student as well.

I think you should emphasize more the option of doing nothing. I saw the reddit post, this happened weeks to months ago. I think most people surrounding this situation simply prefer to forget about it. The most benefit will be gained by doing nothing further.

@AMcKelvy you could also write your own answer, as it sounds at least somewhat distinct from this one.

Positioning is important.
I don't believe you caused any harm by putting out this information, but as others have pointed out, there are some issues with your approach.
Interpretation of the information is not necessary.
You could not be certain that the plan would be carried out. Because of this, it would have been better to report only what you heard. And it would have kept the situation in perspective to include a statement like "keep in mind that I cannot confirm the veracity of this information, I do not wish to speculate, and I am passing it along only for your consideration." It is for others to interpret independently. That you overheard those words spoken is a fact, but anything beyond that is speculation. By including such a disclaimer you would be passing along the information in tact, unaltered, untainted by opinion, and with the reminder that there may be more context that ought to be considered when interpreting it.
The responsibility is not yours.
It's their leak, not yours. You were passing by, in a space you were permitted to be in. You didn't break into an office and start ruffling through documents to obtain this information. Someone with a big mouth inadvertently tipped you off. Passing the information along is not immoral, especially since it involves an organization, not an individual. Which brings us to the next point:
There appear to be no privacy or safety concerns.
This information does not concern an individual's personal information. If it had been a matter of personal privacy, then it would most likely be more appropriate to keep quiet - as long as it's not a matter involving an individual's intent to commit a criminal or harmful act against others. Also, you are not endangering anyone, since the nature of the information is not such that it would compromise anyone's safety.
You're better off anon.
It would have been to your benefit to take steps to protect your anonymity. Luckily, being identified as the leaker probably won't cause you any serious problems in your life. You haven't committed any crimes, you are not subject to any NDAs, and you haven't committed a transgression against anyone personally. It will probably pose an inconvenience for some people - but it also may help others. And you may never fully know the impact. You could have avoided backlash if you had planned more carefully when disseminating the information.
It's always case-by-case.
These kinds of situations vary from one case to another, in terms of who stands to gain or lose, what is ethical or unethical, and how much risk might be involved. It seems you were coming from a position of intent to help the underdogs, which is commendable. But not everyone will see it this way. Sometimes you can come forward with information that helps people, but still suffer for it.
Good luck managing whatever fallout comes from this. It's a life experience. Hopefully the spreading of the information will be more beneficial than harmful.
